# Adding face to an existing face

Tags: azure, azure-cognitive-services, face-api

What is the best practice in `Azure FACE API` to add person face to the trained person.

Is it advisable to add face again and again ? Using,

```
_faceServiceClient.AddPersonFaceAsync(GroupId, PersonId, stream);
```

Comment: Sorry but I don't understand your question. Are you talking about the number of faces that "should" be added to a person?

Comment: @NicolasR I understand with a single face training also, faces can be detected. But till when we should keep on adding the face to the person ?

Comment: Depends on the quality of your tests